# Filter the Jenkins executor list to only the active ones

Tags: jenkins

The company I work for uses a large Jenkins server with a large number of slaves to handle the build and testing for a particular product.  The large number of slaves, many with numerous executor slots, makes for a very long list of slaves/executors in our typical Jenkins view.

Many users have asked if this view could be compressed, down to just a list of slaves with only those executors that are active appearing.  For example; assume that Slave A has 2 executors, both idle and Slave B has 2 executors, one active.  The display would look like this:

Slave A (2 available)
Slave B (1 available)
  1: Building Job A

Instead of the typical view (using the same example):
Slave A
  1: Idle
  2: Idle
Slave B
  1: Idle
  2: Building Job A

I search for a plugin that would do this, or any native behavior, but didn't see anything like this.  Does anyone know if it is possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a view, you can also set the view to show only the slaves that are relevant to the view.

Every user can also create their own views and set their own default view.

It is not exactly what you asked, but AFAIK this is the only way to limit the number slaves displayed.

Comment: This appears to be the best way to do what I want with the existing Jenkins and the existing plugins. Maybe a future plugin with do what I want.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JasonSwager sooo its 2019 and i'm having the same issue. did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @DTaylor Not a feasible one. Since then, we've branched out to more and smaller Jenkins masters, so the list shrinks. And when possible have replaced persistent slaves with ephemeral docker based ones, which helps.  But there are still moments when the slave list is really, really long and you keep on scrolling....

Answer (score -1):

We have exactly the same issue recently. So I made a simple plugin for it. It basically has a switch to either show or hide all the offline nodes. If anyone still needs it or want to add more features, you can go to [this link](https://github.com/markHaoChen/jenkins-build-executors-plugin) and download the plugin.